# Oracle Query for Clob Data Types

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with a huge Oracle database which anybody doesn't know about it and without database diagram.
My question is I need to find all Clob data typed columns in all tables for this database.
Is there any way to query for get all clob data type values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the privileges, you can access the ALL_TAB_COLUMNS system table:

```
SELECT OWNER, 
  TABLE_NAME, 
  COLUMN_NAME 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
  WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'CLOB'
```

Comment: As per A Hocevar if you have a particular user then u can use owner column of this ALL_TAB_COLUMNS table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DbVisualizer (https://www.dbvis.com/) compatible in jdbc with Oracle. If you have the right credentials, you should be able to get ERD diagrams and visually see clob data types.

Now if you need to decode these clob values later on, use an ORM instead.